# what has been done when URL.openconnection()?

Tags: java, url, httpurlconnection

I want to know what has been done when URL.openconnection().
i have done some test like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //    testConnection("http://www.google.com");
    testConnection("http://219.09.34.23.1");
}

private static void testConnection(final String _url) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        String strurl = _url;
        long starttime = 0;
        long endtime = 0;

        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("open:" + strurl);

                starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("starttime:" + starttime);

                URL url = new URL(strurl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();

                endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("openConnection endtime:" + endtime);
                System.out
                        .println("spend:" + (endtime - starttime) + " ms");

                conn.connect();
                endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("connect endtime2:" + endtime);
                System.out
                        .println("spend:" + (endtime - starttime) + " ms");

                conn.getResponseCode();
                endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("endtime3:" + endtime);
                System.out
                        .println("spend:" + (endtime - starttime) + " ms");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("MalformedURLException endtime:"
                        + endtime);
                System.out
                        .println("spend:" + (endtime - starttime) + " ms");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println(" IOException endtime:" + endtime);
                System.out
                        .println("spend:" + (endtime - starttime) + " ms");
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

when i run testConnection("http://www.google.com"), all things are ok.
when i run testConnection("http://219.09.34.23.1"), "219.09.34.23.1" is a random ip maybe not exist i wrote, it print this:

```
open:http://219.09.34.23.1
starttime:1338978920350
openconnection endtime:1338978920355
spend:5 ms

    java.net.UnknownHostException: 219.09.34.23.1  
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)  
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)  
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:37)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

IOException endtime:1338978920393
spend:43 ms
```

it means it spent 5ms to run openconnection, and spent 43ms to find it is a unknownhost, my problem is, what has been done when URL.openconnection() as "219.09.34.23.1" is unknownhost?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: like what? what is your intention? please edit to a real question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you read the [javadocs for `URL.openConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29), you'll find:

> Returns a `URLConnection` instance that represents a connection to the
>   remote object referred to by the URL.
>
> A new instance of `URLConnection` is created every time when invoking
>   the `URLStreamHandler.openConnection(URL)` method of the protocol
>   handler for this URL.
>
> It should be noted that a `URLConnection` instance does not establish
>   the actual network connection on creation. This will happen only when
>   calling `URLConnection.connect()`.

**Update**

The IP you used in your "random ip" is not valid; it should consist of 4 octets, not 5. The 43ms is probably for: (1) doing a DNS lookup on the non-IP ip (2) printing the stack trace.

Comment: i have seen that docs, another question is that in which scene an IOException will be thrown as declaration of the method(URL.openconnection) since an actual network connection is only established when calling URLConnection.connect()

Comment: @YunfeiTang In the case that the URL can't be resolved for example.

Answer (score 11):

**Open connection is not like connect**

`openconnection` does not let you download URL content that's for sure.
You have to call `connect`. But not really, the following will explain:

You are not always required to explicitly call the `connect` method to initiate the connection. Operations that depend on being connected, like `getInputStream`, `getOutputStream`, etc, will implicitly perform the connection, if necessary.

Comment: Wow, I have been searching a while for this answer. I haven't been able to find any documentation the says that `connect()` can be implicitly called, but that sure matches the behavior of URLConnection.

Comment: Benjamin, can you please turn your down vote to an up vote if you think that the answer now is correct?