# How it comes that URL.openConnection() allows me to read header?

Tags: java, networking

I recently was experimenting with java networking and I found a bit odd thing, suppose you have

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
```

then i can call methods, like `con.getContentLength()` and so on and they will give me correct values, even despite I didn't envoke `con.connect()`. How can that be? I mean, where from/how does URLConnection gets those headers, I didn't invoke `con.connect()` yet, so no requests were sent and so no headers should be available at that moment.

Comment: "so no requests were sent". calls for a fact check. Try tcpdump, fiddler, ethereal, wireshark, try disabling the network. My 99% guess: it connects for you when needed. (Edit: in fact, I'd assume `url.openConnection()` to open the connection - what else would be the use of the method)

Comment: Tried unplugging cable, in that case I can't read headers. fiddler shows nothing. Not sure how to use tcpdump, will try wireshark.

Comment: No need, really? You've already established that it _does_ in fact make a connection.

Comment: Since this behavior explicitly goes against the documentation, and the classes have been in the JDK for a long time, I have to believe that you're doing something that you're not showing here. Can you create a simple stand-alone program that demonstrates this behavior and put it in your post? Also, Java version would be useful.

Comment: basicly, i'm doing url connection to shared google doc file. The problem is I can't see, what's happening inside, as all conection goes through https

Comment: possible duplicate of [what has been done when URL.openconnection()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916219/what-has-been-done-when-url-openconnection)

Comment: @parsifal As others have noted, this is mostly like implicitely `connect()`-ing. Also relevant: [Does new URL(…).openConnection() necessarily imply a POST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391/does-new-url-openconnection-necessarily-imply-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

The actual TCP connect happens implicitly when you call any method that requires the response, such as getContentLength(), getInputStream(), getResponseCode(). It doesn't happen at openConnection(). The request is sent at that point.

*Unless* you are using one of the streaming modes and you're doing a PUT or POST with request content, in which case the connection is opened when you start writing the request.

Comment: what kind of connection is made when i use getContentLength(). AFAIK, http only allows 5 or 6 message types (GET, POST, etc), which of them is made here?

Comment: Unless you change the method, it is POST if you have called setDoOutput(true), otherwise GET. This is all documented.

Comment: Where it's documented, I didn't found any documentation about `openConnection` besides, "it doesn't do anything until you invoke method `connect`", also no documentation on `getContentLength`, except "it returns content Length". Could you please elaborate on "This is all documented" ?